# How to fix my regex to check www. part correctly?

Tags: regex

I have this regex where as you can see `www.` is optional

```
(https:\/\/)(?:www\.)?([^\.\/][\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])
```

But this regex would match

```
https://w.youtube.com
```

or

```
https://w...youtube.com
```

for example, because it would think that `w.` is a part of another group. But I want to prevent matching `ww.` or `w.` or `w...`. It should be `www.` or nothing at all.

Comment: Try `https:\/\/(?!w{1,2}\.)(?:www\.)?([^\.\/][\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])`

Comment: Try following expression.

    (http|https):\/\/([w]{3})([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])

For debugging regex, use this [link](https://www.debuggex.com)

Comment: What other groups do you want to allow?

Comment: @Bergi any other url-specific groups

Comment: Then use `https://(?!w\.|ww\.)…`. Although I still don't get the reason for that, they're legit urls as any other.

Comment: or `https:\/\/(?!ww?\.)`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
https:\/\/(?!w{1,2}\.)(?:www\.)?([^.\/][\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])
https:\/\/(?!ww?\.)(?:www\.)?([^.\/][\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])
```

The added part is the `(?!w{1,2}\.)` negative lookahead after `https://`. It matches a location that is not immediately followed with one or two `w` chars followed with a literal dot.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uSh0ek/1).

To also match `http://`, make the `s` optional, `https?:\/\/`.